How to manage non existent or empty paths?
I have a plumber file with multiple paths. I would like to add a validation so if a user tries to access the API without the proper path or verb, it returns a 404 error. I have tried adding a @filter unresponsive_url this but its catching all requests and returning the 404 error
### Libraries
library(plumber)
###


########### 
####Default function

#* @filter unresponsive_url
function(req, res) {
  # Check if a route has been matched
  if (is.null(req$handler) || req$handler$name == "notfound") {
    # If no route has been matched or if it's a not found route, set the status code to 404
    res$status <- 404
    
    # Convert response to JSON format
    res$body <- jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE,
                                 list(status = res$status,
                                      code = 1,
                                      unitid = "123456",
                                      message = "Not Found"
                                 )
    )
    
    # Return the response
    return(res)
    
  } else {
    # If a route has been matched, pass the request to the next handler
    plumber::forward()
  }
}



#* @post /api/v1/path1
#* @param intent 
#* @param deviceid 

function(intent, deviceid, res)
{
  require(DBI)
  require(odbc)
  require(glue)
  require(tibble)
  require(dplyr)
  require(parsedate)
  require(jsonlite)
  require(stringr)
  require(R.utils)
  require(log4r)
  
  options(digits.secs = 3)
  
  log_file = "/app/logs/micirugia.log"
  file_logger = log4r::logger("INFO", appenders = file_appender(log_file, layout = default_log_layout(time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
  
  return(res)
}

#* @post /api/v1/path2
#* @param intent 
#* @param deviceid 

function(intent, deviceid, res)
{
  require(DBI)
  require(odbc)
  require(glue)
  require(tibble)
  require(dplyr)
  require(parsedate)
  require(jsonlite)
  require(stringr)
  require(R.utils)
  require(log4r)
  
  options(digits.secs = 3)
  
  log_file = "/app/logs/micirugia.log"
  file_logger = log4r::logger("INFO", appenders = file_appender(log_file, layout = default_log_layout(time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
  
  return(res)
}


#* @post /api/v1/path3
#* @param intent 
#* @param deviceid 

function(intent, deviceid, res)
{
  require(DBI)
  require(odbc)
  require(glue)
  require(tibble)
  require(dplyr)
  require(parsedate)
  require(jsonlite)
  require(stringr)
  require(R.utils)
  require(log4r)
  
  options(digits.secs = 3)
  
  log_file = "/app/logs/micirugia.log"
  file_logger = log4r::logger("INFO", appenders = file_appender(log_file, layout = default_log_layout(time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
  
  return(res)
}

